Is Spring Cloud OpenFeign have a future
Write now I am writing new spring application using spring boot 3.x. I would like to know if there is a longer support for Spring Cloud OpenFeign.
I have already used the Spring Cloud OpenFeign. but would like to know if this feature has long term support

See this Spring Cloud announcement.
